# SplDoublyLinkedList - how to fetch nodes surrounding current node

Tags: php, doubly-linked-list, spl

Got a question about PHP's SplDoublyLinkedList. If the nature of doubly linked lists is that every node has a reference to nodes on both left and right, why doesn't SplDoublyLinkedList offer methods to retrieve those neighbouring nodes based on current node?

```php
$q = new SplDoublyLinkedList;
$q->push('A');
$q->push('B');
$q->push('C');
for ($q->rewind(); $q->valid(); $q->next()) {
    $current = $q->current();
    // $prev = $q->prev();
    // $next = $q->next();
}
```

In the example above `prev()` and `next()` move iteration cursor. Is there a way of knowing what precedes and follows `$current` without resorting to `$q->key()` and `$q->offsetGet($pos)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of prev and next values yourself, easier if you modify that for loop to use a while loop instead:

```
$prev = null;
$q->rewind();
while ($q->valid()) {
    $current = $q->current();
    echo 'PREV: ', $prev, PHP_EOL;
    echo 'CURRENT: ', $current, PHP_EOL;
    $prev = $current;
    $q->next();
    $next = $q->current();
    echo 'NEXT: ', $next, PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2deOX)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. I just found it strange that while an accent is made on the two-way links between elements, there is no way to use those links.

Comment: next and prev allow you to traverse the array forward or backward, although you can just as easily play with the traversal mode for that purpose.... and what you wanted to achieve could be done using next an prev, but you'd need to keep track of where you were in the array, and test explicitly for valid, and that gets more complex